# I found bug in ruby 1.9.2 Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was running code in ruby console and I suddenly found console crahsed with error below.

/home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90: [BUG] Segmentation fault

ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

-- control frame ----------

```
   c:0015 p:0106 s:0053 b:0053 l:001904 d:001ed4 BLOCK  /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90
   c:0014 p:0007 s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 METHOD /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:22
   c:0013 p:0063 s:0044 b:0044 l:001904 d:001904 METHOD /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:81
   c:0012 p:0118 s:0039 b:0039 l:000038 d:000038 METHOD /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13
   c:0011 p:0269 s:0034 b:0034 l:00165c d:00165c METHOD /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:265
   c:0010 p:0231 s:0029 b:0029 l:001f00 d:001f00 METHOD /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70
   c:0009 p:0063 s:0025 b:0025 l:000016 d:000024 BLOCK  /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54
   c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
   c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :tap
   c:0006 p:0721 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 TOP    /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
   c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
   c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
   c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0012e4 d:0007f4 EVAL   script/rails:6
   c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
   c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0012e4 d:0012e4 TOP
```

---- - Ruby level backtrace information ------------

```
    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in         `<top (required)>'
    /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
   /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
   /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
   /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:81:in `start'
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:22:in `start'
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `block in start'
```

-- C level backtrace information ---------

```
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x72) [0xd19702]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x56757) [0xbf1757]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0x3a) [0xbf184a]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x10a6d4) [0xca56d4]
     /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_thread_run+0x22) [0xd1ead2]
    /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so(+0x7bfc) [0x17abfc]
    /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_threadptr_exec_event_hooks+0xdd) [0xd19d6d]
    /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x179474) [0xd14474]
    /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16e100) [0xd09100]
    /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x173728) [0xd0e728]
    /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x62) [0xd11562]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_obj_tap+0x22) [0xc41f52]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16880d) [0xd0380d]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17941e) [0xd1441e]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16e100) [0xd09100]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x173728) [0xd0e728]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x15b) [0xd0eceb]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x5bcbf) [0xbf6cbf]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x602)        [0xbf8362]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_f_require+0x26) [0xbf8646]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x168803) [0xd03803]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17941e) [0xd1441e]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16e100) [0xd09100]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x173728) [0xd0e728]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0x1f2) [0xd0eb62]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x5905a) [0xbf405a]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x25) [0xbf4095]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x35) [0xbf5815]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby(main+0x68) [0x80487f8]
   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6) [0x4f8bd6]
   /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby() [0x80486f1]
```

[NOTE]
**You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.**
For details: (http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html)[http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html]

Aborted

Kindly let me know if any solution of this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the right place to report a bug in ruby.

As your bug report already stated, go to http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html and perform the steps the web page lists there to report the bug.

Comment: Carsten is right, you should take a look at the Ruby Bugtracker first and report it there http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/issues

Comment: also make sure the bug can be reproduced with some regularity, otherwise the report will not be of much help